# Read from JSON file and add all listings to a message that builds all the listings to show in one. (Hard to explain)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am working on a Discord.JS bot. This is sort of hard for me to explain but, I am making a like "What is supported" command for something and I want to add all entries into a JSON file.

Each entry should be put in a total in the message like, if I had like `"20.0.47.2", "Supported"` and then on another line `"21.0.0.1", "Unsupported"`, I want to put them both together in the message to say like:

```
What's Supported!?
v20.0.47.2 is Supported :)
v21.0.0.1 isn't Supported :(
```

How would I do it?

(If you need more details, please say. I'm just not sure what to do.)

Comment: what did you try? the question does not explain your problem

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have a JSON object like the following...

```
{
    "20.0.47.2": "Supported",
    "21.0.0.1": "Unsupported"
}
```

...you can use `Object.entries()` to get an array of key-value pairs from the object, which you can use in a `for...of` loop to construct your message.

here's some example code:

```js
const supportedVersions = {
  "20.0.47.2": "Supported",
  "21.0.0.1": "Unsupported"
};

let message = "What's Supported?!";

// Object.entries(supportedVersions) == [["20.0.47.2", "Supported"], ["21.0.0.1", "Unsupported"]]
for (let [version, status] of Object.entries(supportedVersions)) {
  if (status === "Supported") {
    message += `\n${version} is Supported :)`
  } else {
    message += `\n${version} isn't Supported :(`
  }
}

console.log(message);
// What's Supported?!
// 20.0.47.2 is Supported :)
// 21.0.0.1 isn't Supported :(
```

note that you can accomplish the same thing in a cleaner way by using booleans instead of string values.